# Ruby Mechanize - How to Click Javascript Link

Tags: python, ruby, mechanize

I've successfully created a script in python with mechanize to log in to a website and do some tasks like downloading files. As long as there is no Javascript these tasks are "simple".

Now I would like to do the same in Ruby with mechanize. Specifically, I would like to "click" the following link:

```
<a id="WebGridFiles_ctl02_Linkbutton3" name="Linkbutton3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('WebGridFiles$ctl02$Linkbutton3','')">Download</a>
```

On this site is another Button, `BackButton1`. If I make a simple `form.submit()` I'll get one site back.

My working python solution:

```
#Build Browser   
...

br["__EVENTTARGET"] = 'WebGridFiles$ctl02$Linkbutton3'
br["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ''
br.find_control("BackButton1").disabled = True
response = br.submit()
response
...
#Browser End
```

I'm wondering how to disable `BackButton1` and perform the submit in Ruby.

Comment: @durron597 thank you for correction

Comment: You're welcome. Stack Overflow is a site for expert questions and answers; it is not a forum. Questions about background, saying thank you, etc. distract from keeping expert advice available for you and for posterity. See [No Thanks, Damn It!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/1768232) and [ask]

Comment: I would guess you just ignore the BackButton1 line, I'm not sure what that's supposed to do, it looks like a bug workaround that ruby wouldn't have anyway.

Comment: As i wrote, if i don't disable the BackButton1 in python and perform the submit, the browser will take me back. Same in Ruby.